# How can I click on an email in Gmail to select it instead of open it?

Tags: gmail

I would like to select an email by clicking on it instead of opening it to be able to perform an action, such as archiving or deleting it.

[image: Email conversation in Gmail]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way is to tick the checkbox you can see in most left of each email listing.